# Loading images into a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I'm hoping somebody can help me out here, I'm not sure what else to do. I have a UIScrollView that loads a set of 44 images, and then allows the user to page through them. My code was working, then suddenly it stopped. I have no idea what I have changed so any help would be much appreciated:

The previous view is a UITableView, it passes a string along with the name of the cell that was selected. Here is the ViewDidLoad Method from the ScrollView:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Answer"
                                                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                                   target:self
                                                                   action:@selector(answerPressed:)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;

    if([questionSetName isEqualToString:@"Limitations"]){

        [self limitationsView];
    }
}
```

Here is the limitationsView:

```
-(void)limitationsView{

    UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -44, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;

    NSArray *unsortedArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:@"Images/Limitations"];

    NSMutableArray *limitationImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int x = 0; x<[unsortedArray count]; x++) {

        NSString *fileName = [[unsortedArray objectAtIndex:x] lastPathComponent];

        [limitationImages insertObject:fileName atIndex:x];
    }

    NSArray *sortedArray = [limitationImages sortedArrayUsingFunction:finderSortWithLocal
                                                              context:(__bridge void *)([NSLocale currentLocale])];

    for(int i = 0; i< [sortedArray count]; i++){

        CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.view.bounds.size.width;

        UIImageView *limitationImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];;

        [limitationImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[sortedArray objectAtIndex:i]]];

        limitationImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

        [scroll addSubview:limitationImageView];

    }

    scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * [sortedArray count], self.view.frame.size.height);

    [self.view addSubview:scroll];


}
```

When I get to the end of the LimitationsView method the sortedArray contains all 44 images, and the proper names, if I try and set the background color of the scrollview I can successfully do that. but my images are not loading and I am at a loss as to why?

Comment: I would suggest using NSLog(@"image:%@",[UIImage imageNamed:[limitationsArray objectAtIndex:i]]); to see if the image is null at that point. If that's the case, then there is a problem with the strings you are storing in that array i.e., they are not identical to the actual names of your images

Comment: Thank you - You were correct that log did show up as nil, The issue had to do with the pathing that I was using. Once I updated to the correct path everything worked perfectly. -Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using

```
NSLog(@"image:%@",[UIImage imageNamed:[limitationsArray objectAtIndex:i]]);
```

to see if the image is null at that point. If that's the case, then there is a problem with the strings you are storing in that array i.e., they are not identical to the actual names of your images